# image does not load (HTML)

Tags: html, image

I have a very simple question : my image does not load with that simple code.. do you have any explanation ?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <body>
     <h2>my image</h2>
         <img src="C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\desert.jpg" alt="image"/>
   </body>
</html>
```

**Note : i am working locally on my computer using WampServer**

I am 100% sure of the path (it displays the image if I copy/paste it directly in the url bar of firefox). 
I also tried to put the image directly in the same folder as the html file...
I tried with firefox/chrome/IE with no success.

Something strange though : it works if I use online image...

Comment: If you're using a WAMP server you "should" serve your images from your server (using http://localhost - or something). Currently you're serving them from your local disc.

Comment: It might have something to do with a space in your url - "Sample Pictures"

Comment: Im gonna assume you didnt, but when you put the image in the same folder as your html, did you change the image url to desert.jpg instead of C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\desert.jpg? Aka: `<img src="desert.jpg" alt="image"/>`

Comment: It works perfectly without any change in your code..may be some problem with the file permissions..

Comment: check for any console errors in your browser..

Comment: @Lal I work on windows, I believe there is no permission right ?
And when i inspect the page it says : "could not load the image"

Comment: is there an error like `ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND` or something like that in the console?

Comment: @Arcyno What is the url when you paste the path in the browser ?

Comment: never mind it just worked with the solution below.. i can't understand why it didn't just 2mn ago !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use a URL, in this case: `file:///C:/Users/Public/Pictures/Sample%20Pictures/desert.jpg`

Comment: Thx for the quick reply ! But unfortunately it still does not work...
(however it loads the image when i paste this directly inside the url bar)

Comment: never mind it just worked with this solution.. i can't understand why it didn't just 2mn ago ! 
thx all for your help

Comment: @Arcyno Im guessing there might have been a caching issue in your browser. I would recommend getting an extension that clears out the cache or if you are on Chrome with the Dev Tools open you can long press the reload button and it gives you options to clean reload from there.

Comment: Actually it seems that an absolute path do not work with WampServer. Locally you have to put all the files you need inside the wamp directory, and access it with relative path..
(but what is strange is that I can read a Json file in absolute path, but not the images !)

Answer (score 0):

Try to create a folder named 'Project' in which put your index.html and create another folder named 'images' and dishes in which your images.

like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
 <h2>my image</h2>
     <img src="images\desert.jpg"    
alt="image"/>
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

To load a picture from a web browser, rather than using a path with the drive letter, you better use the following format :

**file:///C:\yourpath...**

On WampServer it won't work because your browser won't allow to display local content from your machine.

For Mozilla Firefox
To accept it, follow these steps :

1. go to "%appdata%\Mozilla\Firefox\profiles\xxxxxxxx.default"
2. edit users.js or prefs.js
3. add following lines : `user_pref("capability.policy.policynames", "localfilelinks");
   user_pref("capability.policy.localfilelinks.sites", "http://monserveurlocal");
   user_pref("capability.policy.localfilelinks.checkloaduri.enabled", "allAccess");`

You should now be able on Firefox, using Wamp, to see from local path the elements.

Answer (score 0):

Multiple tings may be causing your loading issue:

1. you are using WAMP which is a server but your are using a file path
   to request the file as if you are on the computer and looking it up
   in a folder. You need to look up the file where the web server
   thinks it is instead of where the computer operating file system
   thinks the file is.
2. Windows allows spaces in directory and file names, but most web servers do not.

Assuming that "C:\Users\Public\Pictures\" is where the WAMP web server thinks public files are available at to serve, then you would want to create an "images" directory in in and put your image file in that directory and then reference it like `<img src="/images/filename.jpg alt="">`